# Is invoking methods on slot children in LWCs possible?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slots

I have an LWC that wraps other child LWCs via a `slot`:

```
<template>
    ...
    <div class="sections-content-container">
        ...
        <slot></slot>
        ...
```

and would like to execute a method on each child LWC, guarded by a [duck typing](http://wiki.c2.com/?DuckTyping) check `typeof child.save === "function"`. But when I `this.template.querySelector('slot')` the child LWCs are not available.

(This is a variation of [Call Methods on Child Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_javascript_methods) where no slots are used.)

Is there a pattern that can accomplish this, short of broadcasting a [LMS message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it in the docs in "Access Elements Passed Via Slots" of the [Pass Markup into Slots](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots) page:

> However, the DOM elements that are passed into the slot aren’t part of
> the component’s shadow tree. To access elements passed via slots, a
> component calls **this.querySelector()** and **this.querySelectorAll()**.

compared to the normal `this.template.querySelector()` and `this.template.querySelectorAll()`.

With this, I can invoke the methods.

**PS**

For my case where I want to match any immediate child elements of the slot this selector works well:

```
this.querySelectorAll('*')
```

Comment: An undocumented exception to this rule is elements dragged and dropped into slots in LWR sites using Experience Builder (see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/get_started_layout.htm). To access these elements, apparently we have to use `this.template.querySelector()`/`this.template.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Thanks @MatthewSouther for posting this. It's the sort of thing that can waste lots of time...